# Issues with Boost Linking/Build in Dev-C++

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, boost, mingw

I'm trying to compile a personal program that uses the Boost/Regex library in Orwell Dev-C++ with TDM-GCC 4.8.2 64 bit Release, and when I attempt to initialize a `Boost::Regex` object I get these error messages.

```
text$_ZN5boost9re_detail27cpp_regex_traits_char_layerIcEC2ERKNS0_21cpp_regex_traits_baseIcEE[_ZN5boost9re_detail27cpp_regex_traits_char_layerIcEC2ERKNS0_21cpp_regex_traits_baseIcEE]+0x2b): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_char_layer<char>::init()'
regex_tester_main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail11raw_storage6extendEy[_ZN5boost9re_detail11raw_storage6extendEy]+0x5f): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::raw_storage::resize(unsigned long long)'
regex_tester_main.o: bad reloc address 0x5f in section `.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail11raw_storage6extendEy[_ZN5boost9re_detail11raw_storage6extendEy]'
```

I've followed this [guide](http://andres.jaimes.net/718/how-to-install-the-c-boost-libraries-on-windows/) to install Boost and I used gcc as my toolkit parameters for the bootstrap.bat and the b2 builder. I've included the *include* and *lib* paths in my includes and library options. And lastly linked the appropriate libboost_regex*.a file. Before this I tried using the mingw toolkit option for the bootstrap and gcc option for b2 like the tutorial linked above does, and encountered the same errors. Can anyone shed insight into what has gone wrong?

Comment: A minimal source and compilation command would be helpful (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

I also have the Haskell GHC installed which comes packaged with a mingw/GCC package which was located earlier in the PATH environment variable than the TDM-GCC/minGW-64 package I was aiming to use to build Boost. And so when I specified my toolset it was targeting the wrong complier and thus when I tried to build other programs with Boost it probably ran into some name-mangling issues. I removed GHC's mingw/GCC complier package from PATH and rebuilt Boost, it complies and links fine now :).